# Non-symmorphic lattice

Tags: geometry, lattices

I would like to implement an algorithm for designing this non-symmorphic lattice
[image]

This has a Glide reflection axis runs northeast-southwest.

Comment: Do you at least have code for generating a single tile?

Comment: I am fine if a single tile of this lattice is a rectangle.

Comment: @J.M. nope, but a single tile can be a rectangle. Sorry for not specifying this information.

Answer (score 6):

First we recognize that we might not want to work with rectangles, but with tile elements that look like this.

```
tile =
  {Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}], Line[{{0, 1}, {2, 1}}], 
   Line[{{0, 2}, {2, 2}}], Line[{{0, 1}, {0, 2}}], 
   Line[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}}], Line[{{2, 0}, {2, 1}}], 
   Line[{{2, 0}, {2, 2}}], Line[{{3, 0}, {3, 2}}], 
   Line[{{4, 1}, {4, 2}}], Line[{{2, 0}, {4, 0}}], 
   Line[{{3, 1}, {4, 1}}], Line[{{2, 2}, {3, 2}}]};

Graphics[tile]
```

[image: tile]

Given that we need two translation functions.

```
t0 = Translate[tile, {4 #1, 2 #2}] &;
t2 = Translate[tile, {2 + 4 #1, 2 #2}] &;
```

Now we can draw the tiling.

```
Graphics[Function[n, {t0[#, n], t2[#, 1 + n]} & /@ Range[0, 4]] /@ Range[0, 8, 2]]
```

[image: tiling]

Comment: Can't you use this approach to generate polygons too?

Answer (score 3):

This is a step by step setup for a textured image.

We can generate rectangles at proper distance with:

```
   Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], White, 
  Table[Rectangle[{i, 0}, {i + 2, 1}], {i, 0, 6, 4}]}]
```

[image]

Then lets add a vertical rectangle:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], White, 
  Table[{Rectangle[{i, 0}, {i + 2, 1}], 
    Rectangle[{i + 2, -1}, {i + 3, 1}]}, {i, 0, 6, 4}]}]
```

[image]

The horizontal rectangle to the top and right of the initial one, is given by increasing both `x` and `y` by `1`, for which we'll use a new iterator:

```
{Rectangle[{i + j, j}, {i + j + 2, j + 1}], 
 Rectangle[{i + 2 + j, -1 + j}, {i + 3 + j, 1 + j}]}
```

Now generate a function which will do everything including a good plotting range:

```
tiles[n_] :=

 Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], White, 
   Table[{Rectangle[{i + j, j}, {i + j + 2, j + 1}], 
     Rectangle[{i + 2 + j, -1 + j}, {i + 3 + j, 1 + j}]}, {i, 0, 
     2n, 4}, {j, n}]}, PlotRange -> {{n, 2+ 2n}, {1, n}}]
```

If you want to generate an actual textured tileset, you need to use polygons:

```
tileim = Import["https://i.imgsafe.org/d2eee03f00.png"];
tilesG[n_] := 
 Graphics[{Texture[tileim], 
   Table[{Polygon[{{i + j, j}, {i + j, j + 1}, {i + j + 2, 
        j + 1}, {i + j + 2, j}}, 
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}}], 
     Polygon[{{i + 2 + j, -1 + j}, {i + 2 + j, 1 + j}, {i + 3 + j, 
        1 + j}, {i + 3 + j, -1 + j}}, 
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 
         0}}]}, {i, 0, 2 n, 4}, {j, n}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{n, 2 + 2 n}, {1, n}}]
tilesG[8]
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of keeping a rotated copy of the texture, just change the `VertexTextureCoordinates` setting of the first set of `Polygon[]`s into `VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}}`.

Comment: To make things easier for other people, you might consider uploading `tile.png` to imgur, and then use `Import[]` to get the image from within *Mathematica*.

Comment: @J.M. Fair enough